# Relationships between $2$ mutually tangent circles in a semi-circle

Tags: geometry, circles

In the attempt to answer [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4052473), I was brought to another one, connected to a certain family of circles.

Consider the semicircle made of the upper half of the unit circle and the horizontal diameter with endpoints $A(-1,0)$ and $B(1,0)$.

Let us now consider the family $(F)$ of circles inscribed into this semicircle as can be seen on Fig. 1.

[image]

*Fig. 1: Certain circles of family $(F).$*

They can be described in a parametric way as circles

$$\text{with center} \ (x_c=-\cos a, y_c=\frac12 \sin^2a) \ \text{and radius} \ y_c, \ a \in (0,\pi) \tag{1}$$

or equivalently as circles $(C_T)$

$$\text{with center} \ \left(x_c=\frac{T^2-1}{(1+T)^2}, y_c=\frac{2T}{(1+T)^2}\right) \ \text{and radius} \ y_c, \ T \in (0,+\infty) \tag{2}$$

(Connection between the two parameterizations: $T=t^2$ where $t:=\tan \tfrac{a}{2}$).

The locus of these centers is parabola $(P)$ with cartesian equation:

$$y=\tfrac12(1-x^2),\tag{3}$$

represented on Fig. 2 as the light blue curve.

Each circle $(C_T) \in F$ is associated with a unique circle $(C_{T'}) \in F$ which is tangent to $(C)$ as depicted on Fig. 2.

[image]

*Fig. 2: Two circles of family $(F)$ are mutually tangent if their parameters $T$ and $T'$ comply with relationship (4).*

Let $I$ be the point of tangency of $(C_T)$ and $(C_{T'})$.

**Question: how can we describe the locus of $I$?**

(sketched as the magenta curve on Fig. 2.)

My work: I have obtained through tedious calculations an unexpected linear relationship between parameters $T$ and $T'$ which is:

$$T=(3-2 \sqrt{2})T'\tag{4}$$

Using (4), I have tried to obtain the locus of $I$ as the envelope of chords defined by the line segment joining the centers of circles $C_T,C_{T'}$ using homographies but to no avail.

---

**Edit: Nice solution using inversion** (a little different from the solution given in a comment by Blue).

'Refer to Fig. 3). Consider inversion with pole $S(0,-1)$ and power $2$ meaning that $M$ is exchanged with $M'$ iff $S,M,M'$ are aligned and $SM.SM'=2$. Its circle of inversion is  the black circle (center $S$, radius $\sqrt{2}$). It is easy to see that any circle of family (F) is *globally* invariant. This is in particular the case for the two blue circles. As the image by inversion of two tangent curves in a certain point $I$ is two tangent curves with contact point $I'$ where $M'$ is the image of $M$, point $I$ is invariant, establishing that $I$ belongs to the circle of inversion.$\square$

As a consequence, tangency points $T_1$ and $U_1$, $T_2$ and $U_2$, are exchanged, meaning that $S,T_1,U_1$ and $S,T_2,U_2$ are aligned.

[image]

*Fig. 3.*

**Remark:** Two properties of circles of family (F) deserving to be known:

http://www.gogeometry.com/problem/p311_circle_inscribed_semicircle_chord.htm

http://www.gogeometry.com/problem/p310_semicircle_circle_tangent_angle.htm

Comment: Does $(y_2(x_1,y_1)+y_1(x_2,y_2))/(y_1+y_2)$ give a nice answer?

Comment: @JeanMarie I understood. Thanks, great method!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's something more fundamental going on here.

---

Consider any circle $\bigcirc P$ tangent to the semicircle $ACB$ at $T$ and the diameter at $T'$. (My figure is rotated.) Let $\overline{CC'}$ be the perpendicular diameter with $C$ the midpoint of the semicircle.

[image]

[Thales' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thales%27s_theorem) guarantees that right angle $\angle CTC'$ subtends parallel diameters of $\bigcirc P$ and $\bigcirc O$; thus, $C'$, $T$, $T'$ are collinear, and $\triangle CTC'\sim\triangle T'OC'$, so that
$$|C'T||C'T'|=|C'C||C'O|=2r^2$$
That is, [the power of $C'$ with respect to $\bigcirc P$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point) is independent of $P$. Consequently,

- the tangent segments from $C'$ to *any circle* is $\sqrt{2r^2}=r\sqrt{2}$; and
- $C'$ lies on the [radical axis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_axis) of *any pair of circles*.

In the specific case of a pair of inscribed circles that are tangent to each other at a point $I$, the mutual tangent line through $I$ is their radical axis, necessarily meeting $C'$. Moreover, $\overline{C'I}$, being a tangent segment to each circle, has length $r \sqrt{2}$. We conclude that $I$ lies on the circle of radius $r\sqrt{2}$ about $C'$. $\square$

Comment: Once again, you pinpoint the "root ideas". I think that a proof using inversion should exist as well.

Comment: @JeanMarie: I try. :) ... Incidentally, if you carry the construction beyond the bounds of the semicircle ---ie, taking the centers *anywhere* along the parabola, and maintaining tangency with the diameter-line--- then the *inscribed* circles of the semicircle become *exscribed* circles of the *other* semicircle, and the locus of $I$ becomes the (almost-) *entire* circle about $C'$.

Comment: @JeanMarie: "I think that a proof using inversion should exist as well." ... Indeed: One can argue without specificity that there's *some* circle through $A$ & $B$ such that inversion exchanges $\overline{AB}$ w/ $\stackrel{\frown}{ACB}$. The inversion preserves tangencies and thus also the family of inscribed circles, and we conclude that the center of inversion ---wherever it may be--- has the requisite radical axis and tangent segment properties for the circle to be the locus of $I$. ... In fact, this argument works even for non-semicircle arcs and non-diameter chords ... and even two arcs!

Comment: A big thank for your comment about the extension to the whole circle and for your inversive proof.

Comment: I just saw two interesting properties [(1)](http://www.gogeometry.com/problem/p310_semicircle_circle_tangent_angle.htm)
 and [(2)](http://www.gogeometry.com/problem/p311_circle_inscribed_semicircle_chord.htm) of circles of family $(F)$:

Comment: @JeanMarie No one usually remembers but angle bisector of a right triangle, $x$, divides hypotenuse into two segments $a,b$ such that $2/x^2=1/a^2+1/b^2$. Similarly (1) should be obvious but didn't strike to me immediately. Nice find. :)

Comment: @Blue I have written a solution using inversion which does not need the use of radical axis.

Comment: @cosmo5 Interesting. Visibly, you have had a solid classical training...

Answer (score 3):

$$(x_1,y_1)=\left(\frac{T-1}{T+1},\frac{2T}{(T+1)^2}\right)\\
(x_2,y_2)=\left(\frac{U-1}{U+1},\frac{2U}{(U+1)^2}\right)\\
(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2=(y_1+y_2)^2\\
\frac{4(T-U)^2}{(T+1)^2(U+1)^2}=4y_1y_2=\frac{16TU}{(T+1)^2(U+1)^2}\\
T^2-6TU+U^2=0$$
The tangent point is $(x,y)=$
$$(y_2(x_1,y_1)+y_1(x_2,y_2))/(y_1+y_2)\\
=\left(\frac{U(T^2-1)+T(U^2-1)}{U(T+1)^2+T(U+1)^2},\frac{4TU}{U(T+1)^2+T(U+1)^2}\right)\\
\frac{4x}y=T-\frac1T+U-\frac1U\\
\frac4y=T+2+\frac1T+U+2+\frac1U\\
\left(\frac4y-4\right)^2=\left(\frac{4x}y\right)^2+4(T+U)(\frac1T+\frac1U)\\
(1-y)^2=x^2+2y^2\\x^2+(y+1)^2=2$$

Comment: Therefore an arc of circle centered in $(0,-1)$ with radius $\sqrt{2}$ ! A (piece of) conic curve...

Answer (score 1):

Observe that the point of tangency divides the segment between the centers in the ratio of the radii, that is, in the ratio $y(T')/y(T)$. Therefore, if you call $(U,V)$ the point of tangency,
$$
U(T)=x(T)+\frac{y(T')}{y(T)}(x(T')-x(T));\quad V(T)=y(T)+\frac{y(T')}{y(T)}(y(T')-y(T))
$$
where $T'$ is expressed through $T$ using the relation you found (assuming it is correct).

Comment: I thought to it (not exactly with this form) but it is not practicaly tractable (for example for solving the initial question).

Comment: @Jean Marie I see..Does your parameter $a$ have a nice geometric meaning?

Comment: Yes, for the meaning ("nice", why not ?): If $\Omega$ is the center of the circle with parameter $a$, you draw a vertical line from $\Omega$. Let $J$ be the intersection of this line with the unit circle. Then $a$ is the angle between  the $x$ axis and $\vec{OJ}$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Apply a transformation that makes the problem simpler ( more symmetric). Given two circle there exists an inversion that transforms them into two circles of equal radii. Now the problem has a (line of ) symmetry.
This can be done in higher dimensions too.

The symmetry line is in fact a circle $C$ such that the reflection in $C$ takes one circle  to the other.  Note that the reflection with respect to a circle is an intrinsic notion in the circle geometry. However, a circle has no center. Only after we choose the point at infinity, its reflection with respect to the circle will be the "center".